# When i read data from child it shows null in Firebase, Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbVRA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WokD8.png)

i am trying to read all the data under 'User' and display them if they have a certain value.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that does that.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). For the database, you can get it s text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.